# How to sum 2 input text numbers using controller in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have 3 input text and one button in my view like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) { 
    <input id="Text1" name="txtNum1" type="text" placeholder="num 1" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'/>

    <input id="Text2" name="txtNum2" type="text" placeholder="num 2" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'/>

    <input id="Text3" name="txtNum3" type="text" readonly="readonly" />

    <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Sum" />

}
```

in my controller ,when i click submit button ,i want to sum the 2 input text and put result in the third text , this is my controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(int txtNum1=0,int txtNum2=0, int txtNum3=0)
{
     txtNum3= txtNum1+ txtNum2;

     return View(txtNum3);
}
```

when i put numbers in the 1st and 2nd text then click submit it post back but i don't show any result in the 3rd text .

 so how can i fix this code?

Comment: you are passing the result of txtNum3 to the view but I don't see the code where the result value is assigned back to the third text. You can use jquery to assign value passed as Model to the third text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a Model class first of all, in your case it will contains three properties as you have three textboxes and the input will be numbers, so use `int`.

Your model class will be :

```
public class SumModel
{
    public int Number1 { get;set;}
    public int Number1 {get;set;}
    pubilc int Result {get { return Number1 + Number2;}}
}
```

then in your view you will need to specify which `Model` it is fimiliar with of, which means which model this view is binded with :

```
@model YourNameSpace.Models.SumModel 
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{ 
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Number1)

    @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Number2)

    @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Result, new {@readonly = "readonly"})

    <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Sum" />

}
```

and in controller action add the parameter of type `SumModel`:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Index(SumModel model)
 {
     return View(model);
 }
```

after the model posted the View will be re-rendered with the third textbox with the sum value of two textboxes.